# Why does NPM install another version then specified?

Tags: npm, npm-install

I worked on a project and pushed it to a bitbucket. After a needed format of my hdd I pulled the project back on my HDD. But when I do the npm install now it installs a different version then specified in the `package.json` package?

[My `package.json` file](https://gist.github.com/nealoke/8f424360ca2d3595509023e11d46256a#file-package-json)

[Output when npm finishes installing](https://gist.github.com/nealoke/8f424360ca2d3595509023e11d46256a#file-cl-output)

Notice the react `v15.5.4` in stead of the specified `v15.3.2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NPM allows you to specify version with semantic [versioning specification](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/semantic-versioning) in which

```
"react": "^15.3.2",
```

means "every minor release of version 15"

Just remove the "^" symbol to install the version you need (or change to "~" if you want to accept patch releases)

Comment: I see..thanks for that info..clearly I was way off with my answer :D.. so does it not make a difference if a package is in dependencies and devDependencies  the way npm installs?

Comment: It installs both by default, unless you specify `NODE_ENV=production` or pass it `--only=production`